# Replace apostrophes in a string

Tags: javascript

```
var ScanLastName = "212227_O'Connell".replace(/'/g, '');

function btnScan_onclick(divToRefresh) 
{
    ScanDoc1 = $('input.scandocument').val();
    ScanDoc = ScanDoc1.replace(/\s/g, '');
    ScanDocFileName = ScanDoc+ScanLastName;
}
```

I don't see the problem.  I get an error that btnScan_onclick is undefined.

I'm trying to remove spaces and apostrophes.

The code was working until I added the code to remove apostrophes.

Comment: Missing `}` at the end of `btnScan_onclick`

Comment: maybe you're trying to call it before it gets defined, or from the wrong scope? (if it's not the `}` issue)

Comment: I wish I could say your horrible variable names were causing the error, but it's probably the missing `}`...

Comment: If I remove all ScanLastName code it works.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you about the value of `ScanDoc1` and `ScanDoc`?

Comment: The example is just part of the code. I'm not missing }

Comment: Well... that's your problem.  Maybe your jQuery selector isn't returning anything.  Have you looked into that?  Use the debugger... It's your friend.  It can help you a lot more than we can (since you've barely shown us any relevant code).

Comment: Whoa! What do you do? Just sit around and look for people to take pot shots at?  I'll try another forum.

Comment: This forum is fine. Just take your time and ask complete questions.  Posting broken code, (e.g. the missing `}` how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: What was a pot shot?  You said _ScanDoc1_ is undefined, so I said that is your problem.  If _ScanDoc1_ is undefined, you won't be able to call `replace()` on it.  Obviously we can't troubleshoot your selector based on what you've shown us.  Recommending the use of a debugger is also an attempt to help.  A debugger is the key to solving JavaScript issues.

Comment: `btnScan_onclick` is undefined? Where are you calling the function? Is it defined in global scope? It would be great if you could provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo, the code you posted does not contain enough information.